# How to solve integrals of the form $\int u^{-\alpha} e^{-\beta u} du$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to simplify an integral of the form $\int u^{-\alpha} e^{-\beta u} du$, where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}^{++}$. Is it a standard integral, or a family that subsumes gamma integrals? Is there any known trick available for the simplification?

Comment: What is the domain of alpha? If alpha is an integer, then you can recursively apply integration by parts, with u^alpha as the first function.

Comment: Since you did not give any restriction for $\alpha$, the answer can be rather difficult. Formally, the result is $$-u^{\alpha +1} (\beta  (-u))^{-\alpha -1} \Gamma (\alpha +1,-u \beta )$$ which also write $$-u^{\alpha +1} E_{-\alpha }(-u \beta )$$ but I do not suppose that you care about these. I presume that $\alpha$ is an integer and then do what  Somabha Mukherjee suggests.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Can you give me the defn. of $E_{-\alpha}$? Is it the exponential integral?

Comment: Yes, it is. Are you familiar with it ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: No, from the Wiki defn, I do not see how you arrive at the transformation from gamma to exp.

Comment: I did not arrive to anywhere ! A CAS did it. But again, if $\alpha$ is an integer, the problem is quite simple as already suggested.

Comment: Hi @ClaudeLeibovici: My main ques. is how we can move from an indefinite integral to a definite integral, as is the case in the definition for $E_\alpha$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17200/discussion-between-bravo-and-claude-leibovici).